# How to refresh a part of the page after some time automatically?

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control loaded on the `default.aspx` page using the

```
Control UControl = null;

UControl = this.LoadControl("UserControl1.ascx");

 UControl.ID = UControl.GetType().Name;
                    panel1.Controls.Add(UControl);
```

Now I want to refresh only the content of the user control not all the page.

I already used

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

and

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "2");
```

But these are refreshing the entire `default.aspx` page.

How I can only refresh the user control without refreshing the `default.aspx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look into the `<asp:UpdatePanel>` control. You can use it with a timer as well to auto refresh, or hook it into a trigger such as button or link.

Try here on the offical asp.net site:

- http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax

But a simple search will also produce plenty of tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ajax Timer Control: http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-timer-control